# No private key for certificate with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild

Since I changed my certificate,I cant build anymore with xcodebuild.

**I can build and export using xcode archive and organizer without issues.
My private key is installed correctly.**

But, when I use xcodebuild manually from the terminal, it first throw errors I don't fully understand and then says that I dont have a private key for my certificate.

**Here is the xcodebuild command I use**

terminal% /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -verbose -scheme MyApp -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -configuration Release clean archive  -archivePath _build/MyApp.xcarchive -allowProvisioningUpdates

**Here is the error**

2020-12-03 07:57:01.238 xcodebuild[4658:241714]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-17535/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/Logging/IDEProvisioningLedger.m:172
Details:  Unable to close provisioning ledger entry because not all of its subentries are closed
Object:   <IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: 0x7ff4f0a54e00>
Method:   -closeWithError:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff4ef32abc0>{number = 11, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

**followed by**

error: Revoke certificate: Your account already has an Apple Development signing certificate for this machine, but its private key is not installed in your keychain.

**I read a lot of posts from people that have a similar issues**

- I check, double checked, revoked so many times my certificats
- I reinstalled command line tools to try and solve the issue.
- I tried specify the keychain in case it could'nt find it alone
- I tried to lock unlock the keychain in case
- I tried it in my own computer and it works fine

I don't know what to do right now to fix the problem apart from re-installing macos completely :(.

PS:

The build machine originally use jenkins 2.244. The error is the same with jenkins.

The version of xCode is Version 12.2 (12B45b)

The os is Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)

*Thank you*

Answer (score 1):

The solution was so simple I'm quite ashamed to have lost this much time on this issue.

The command is building for release so I checked the private key of the distribution certificate and I did not install the developement certificate.

I was so focused on this idea that I did not look back and say "Oh it is talking about developement for a reason (a dumb one) even if I build for distribution"

I just added the Developement certificated and private key to the keychain and it works.

Sow now, I learned that xcodebuild will need the dev certificate and key even when building for distribution.